# Regex - Delete up to second whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I think what i'm trying to do is possible... but I haven't found an answer that achieves  that yet.
I would like to format a string which will be similar to this in javascript:

`+44 (0) 234-567-8901`

The proceeding international ( +44 ) and local ( (0) ) calling code are subject to change, so the string could be longer or shorter. However the format is always the same.

I would like to take this string and remove all characters including whitespaces up to the second whitespace and remove dashes.
e.g:

`+44 (0) 234-567-8901 becomes 2345678901`

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Have a look at `indexOf` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: This is the closest i've got `^[^\)]+(?=\))` which using the example above returns `+4402345678901`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your own requirements (remove everything up to and including the second whitespace, and remove dashes from the remaining);

Use this pattern `^([\S]+\s){2}|-` and replace with nothing. You should be left with a number similar to what you asked for (`+44 (0) 234-567-8901` becomes `2345678901`).

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on the ending format of the string to be a consistent number of characters, you can grab the last 12 characters, and remove the dashes.

```
var result = str.slice(-12).replace(/-/g, "");
```

---

If you really just want a regex, you can do this...

```
var result = str.match(/(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})$/).slice(1).join("");
```

Again, this relies on consistency of the end of the string. If there may be variation, you'll need to adjust to compensate.

---

To get everything after the last whitespace, change the `slice()` in the first example to this...

```
.slice(str.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)
```

To get everything after the second whitespace, change the `slice()` to this...

```
.slice(str.indexOf(' ', str.indexOf(' ') + 1) + 1)
```

Comment: For most cases I could rely on the last 12 characters as these will be UK numbers, however there will be some international numbers so its not a complete solution unfortunately. Is there no way to search by whitespace number and delete everything before?

Comment: @user1535196: If you want everything after the *last* whitespace, do this... `str.slice(str.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)`